# Add adorner to bound children?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, adorner

```
<ItemsControl Name="CanvasTableMap" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
            <WrapPanel   Background="{DynamicResource ContentBackground}" />        
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Button Canvas.Left="100"  Content="{Binding Name}" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonTableTemplate}"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>       
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is my code.No problem with that. I have created an adorner and i would like to add an adorner for each button when i want.  It is a little difficult as i dont know how to get the Buttons. CanvasTableMap.Items  returns the Model so i dont know how to get access to the controls efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do that is to define a handler for the `Loaded` event of the button, and add the adorner in that handler:

**XAML**

```
<Button Canvas.Left="100"  Content="{Binding Name}" ... Loaded="Button_Loaded" />
```

**Code-behind**

```
private void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(button);

    // Add the adorner
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use code-behind, you can create an attached behavior (either with `System.Windows.Interactivity` or by creating an attached property)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to get the control created from the data ([`ContainerFromItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx)). Usually doing things that way is not such a good idea though.

Comment: What is the alternative ?Microsoft official way for adorners is by code. I dont have time to implement hacks. ContainerFromItem  i dont know what parameter to pass

Comment: @Parhs: Uhm. the data item? Didn't you read the documentation?